# eqneditor in tinymce version 4 doesn't work on webhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I use the equation editor plugin from this website http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/tinymce_v4/install.php
to edit equations in tinymce 4.x. Works perfectly on localhost, but when uploading the website to webhost http://000webhost.com , tinymce won't load as long as it uses this plugin. Any idea what the solution could be? All help is highly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image eqneditor charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code  fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | charmap eqneditor | styleselect | bold italic underline superscript subscript | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link jbimages"
    });
</script>
```